# Key to move to next ancestor heading in org mode

Tags: org-mode, motion

I would like to jump to the next parent heading from a lower level directly. Is there a shortcut for that in org mode?

```
* a
** b
** c
* d
```

So to jump, say, from b to d.

Comment: `C-c C-u` to go up to the `a` headline  and `C-c C-f` to go to the `b` headline. Or you can do a macro, or you can define your own function and bind it to whatever key(s) you want.

Comment: i did a macro, it makes more sense, thanks

Comment: I meant to say "...`C-c C-f` to go to the `d` headline" - I wonder why I only see my typos months later :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `C-c C-u` to go to parent then `C-c C-f` to go to next heading of the same level (i.e., sibling)

Comment: The out-of-the-box keybinding for `org-forward-heading-same-level` is `C-c C-f`, not `C-c C-n`: the latter is bound to `org-next-visible-heading`, so it will only go to `d` if the `a` tree is folded.